# Microcontroller controlled power supply

Tags: arduino, voltage-regulator, switching-regulator

Can anyone assist me to make a power supply whose output voltage will be controlled by an Arduino, with the latest voltage setting automatically saved in non volatile memory?

I am in an OJT (On the Job Training Scheme). I was given a task to make a Arduino controlled voltage variable power supply whose outputs can be switched between several preset values using pushbutton control. It's like switching between two different outputs when a designated button is being pushed.

Here is what I have done so far. I made an LM317 based power supply with the output voltage controlled by a potentiometer. I followed this youtube tutorial. It works well but I was ask to upgrade it.

Instead of using a potentiometer to adjust the voltage, I wish to use switching buttons to choose between two or more preset voltage levels. Each switch buttons have their corresponding voltages.

This link may also be relevant.
Code is given below the circuit diagram.
ARDUINO AS A POWER SOURCE ALTERNATOR

Comment: You need to add significantly more detail to your question.  Is this an automobile alternator?  What voltage?  How much current does the field winding require?

Comment: @DwayneReid No, It's not an automobile alternator. It's a simple adjustable power supply and I've made one. I followed this youtube tutorial [link] (youtube.com/watch?v=F-ahtojVl4M). It works well but I was ask to upgrade it, instead of using a potentiometer in adjusting the voltage, he suggest to have a swicthing buttons which I can swap two or more power sources automatically. Each buttons must have their corresponding voltage outputs. Can you help me figure out how to apply it maybe by using an arduino?

Comment: Why do people need arduino for every single electronics project? Use the push-buttons to switch between different resistors for the LM317 and you will achieve what you want.

Comment: @v.m. Can you give me a circuit diagram of what you have suggested?

Comment: @v.m. Arduino is great as first step to learn interfacing electronics to digital world. I don't see a reason on why not to use Arduino in every single electronics project. Think why someone would control few led's using Arduino?

Comment: Based on what you have done so far, you can replace your potentiometer with a digital potentiometer chip and use the Arduino to control it.

Answer (score 1):

If a adjustable LDO is enough, you could put different discrete resistors in the place of the poti and switch between the resistors with NFET Transistors controlled by the arduino.

Second, there are digital controlled potentiometers out there, but they are expensive and I have never worked with them.

**EDIT:** Below is a really fast and not verified sketch what I think of. Please use with caution. In the end you have to understand yourself what you are doing.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f9GacR.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: This is what the application note (http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm117.pdf) figure 57 proposes. Note to April: it's usually a good idea to look at the datasheet and application notes. I learned tons of stuff only from those sources.

Comment: Okay thanks, can you assist me in doing the circuit diagram?

Comment: @0x6d64 Thanks. Yes I will make a review for those sources.

Comment: You can go with a d-pot at the adjust pin of LM317, and have your Arduino adjust it upon command.

Answer (score 0):

Just throw it out here, in case you like it switch mode (using a boost converter for example, if you need lower voltages go for a buck topology):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2ftNv5h.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Just use a MOSFET with low enough \$R_{ds(on)}\$